# jQuery-mobile popup won't appear at all

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dialog, popup

I'm trying to get a sign in a pop up which was directly copy-pasted from "http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup/". I copied and pasted it to have it go in my listed navigation and when I click on the link simply nothing happens. The URL recognizes to go to .../#popupLogin, but there is no pop up.

HTML segment:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_home">

  <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="bars" data-expanded-icon="bars" id="navbar_links">
      <h3>Menu</h3>
      <a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Sign in</a>
      <a href="#page_home" >Products</a>
      <a href="#page_about">About</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
    <form>
        <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
            <h3>Please sign in</h3>
            <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
            <input name="user" id="un" value="" placeholder="username" data-theme="a" type="text">
            <label for="pw" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
            <input name="pass" id="pw" value="" placeholder="password" data-theme="a" type="password">
            <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your jQuery ? Did you include a link for your script ?

Comment: Yes, the stylesheet link is version 1.4.5 and the js script is version 1.4.5 (both jquery mobile). I also have a script for jquery for version 2.2.0.

Comment: can you put it in fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5zwhjL7c/1/ Here is the fiddle with all the code. I was unable to make it look nice for some reason with the external jquery files. Not sure if that helps but rest assured on my computer nothing breaks at all.

Comment: Fix you code, I can't get what you want to do.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5zwhjL7c/3/, This one is a bit better. Here, click on the iphone link, then click on the menu, then click on Sign in. Nothing happens, I'm asking why it is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I saw them both at the same time. I was led to believe top rated answers should be the most-detailed solution that works so that other users looking for answers could be directed better. If that is not the case, I will let you have .

Comment: OK.....@AndrewRicci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to include the right scripts. There is a quote-mark in the mobile.css link that make's it give 404 and your jQuery version is wrong. Those links are working:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Check this out:

```css
#header1 {
    background-color: #336699;
    border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
    height: 100px;
    position: static;
}

[data-role="header"] h1 {
    font-family: Impact;
    font-size: 40pt;
    color: #FFCC66;
    margin-top: 43px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 25;
}

#navbar {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#h_about {
    text-align: center;
    
}

#p_about {
    margin: 45px;
}

#footer_about {
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 20px;
}

#image_cr {
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

#grid_product {
    margin: 35px;
}

.signin_pop {
    float: right;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 <div data-role="page" id="page_home">
      <div data-role="header" id="header1">
        <div>
            <h1>Cell City</h1>
        </div>
      </div>  

      <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="bars" data-expanded-icon="bars" id="navbar_links">
          <h3>Menu</h3>
          <a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Sign in</a>
          <a href="#page_home" >Products</a>
          <a href="#page_about">About</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
        <form>
            <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
                <h3>Please sign in</h3>
                <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
                <input name="user" id="un" value="" placeholder="username" data-theme="a" type="text">
                <label for="pw" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
                <input name="pass" id="pw" value="" placeholder="password" data-theme="a" type="password">
                <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      
      <div id="grid_product" class="ui-grid-b ui-responsive">
        <div class="ui-block-a grid_block">
          <a href="#page_iphone" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ">
            <image src="images/iphone.jpg" alt="" height="200"/>
          </a><br>
          <a href="#page_iphone">Unlocked Original Iphone 6s 64Gb | Without fingerprint Function 4.7" 1GB RAM 16/64GB ROM 8MP Camera</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b grid_block">
          <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
            <image src="images/motorola.jpg" alt="" height="200"/>
          </a><br>
          <a href="#">Motorola 00491NACRTL 8GB GSM / HSPA / LTE Black Unlocked Cell Phone 5" 1GB RAM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-c grid_block">
          <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
            <image src="images/nokia.jpg" alt="" height="200"/>
          </a><br>
          <a href="#">UNLOCKED Microsoft Nokia Lumia 640 RM-1073, 5" HD LCD, 8MP, 720p, BLACK </a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- ABOUT US PAGE -->   
    <div data-role="page" id="page_about">
      <div data-role="header" id="header1">
        <div>
            <h1>Cell City</h1>
        </div>
      </div>  

      <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="bars" data-expanded-icon="bars" id="navbar_links">
          <h3>Menu</h3>
          <a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Sign in</a>
          <a href="#page_home" >Products</a>
          <a href="#page_about">About</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div id="para_about">
        <h2 id="h_about">About US</h2>
        <p id="p_about">
          Welcome to Cell City a one stop shop for all your cell phone needs. We offer three cell phones and thats all you need,
          We got phones for people of all ages and every phone is equipped with the latest and greatest technology. Not only
          are our phones the best pieces of hardware you will ever touch, but the prices...OH MAN...our prices are absolutely
          unbeatable. Find any phone anywhere for cheaper and we will give you a phone 100% free, THATS RIGHT 100% FREE! Now
          for some Lorum Ipsum to fill up some space.<br><br>
          
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean gravida, dolor convallis volutpat consectetur, 
          mauris justo tempor augue, non ultrices libero elit sed est. Donec sit amet posuere quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. 
          Nunc id ultricies est. Suspendisse vitae egestas mauris. Quisque faucibus, sem blandit cursus dapibus, ipsum quam ultricies 
          neque, et pulvinar diam massa eget quam. Proin scelerisque augue leo. Phasellus orci libero, pretium non diam vel, 
          feugiat rhoncus metus. Etiam neque nisl, porta at placerat vel, tempor sit amet odio. Donec varius viverra justo eu 
          condimentum. Vivamus sagittis lacus ac sapien bibendum, ac hendrerit tellus mollis.<br><br>
          
          Free free to Contact us.<br><br>
          
        </p>
        <footer id="footer_about"><image id="image_cr" src="images/Copyright_symbol.png" alt=""/> Cell City, Established 2016, Copyrights all rights reserved, etc etc | Andrew & Jin Productions</footer>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- IPHONE PAGE -->   
    <div data-role="page" id="page_iphone">
      <div data-role="header" id="header1">
        <div>
            <h1>Cell City</h1>
        </div>
      </div>  

      <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="bars" data-expanded-icon="bars" id="navbar_links">
          <h3>Menu</h3>
          <a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Sign in</a>
          <a href="#page_home" >Products</a>
          <a href="#page_about">About</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2 id="iphone_header">Unlocked Original Iphone 6s 64Gb | Without fingerprint Function 4.7" 1GB RAM 16/64GB ROM 8MP Camera</h2>
      
      <div id="phone_margin" class="ui-grid-a">
        <div id="block_a_75" class="ui-block-a">
          CONTENT A
        </div>

        <div id="block_b_25" class="ui-block-b">
          
          <form action="form.php" method="post">
            
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the jQuery version. Remove the jQuery [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) and add this:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```